# Call QueryInterface before CoCreateInstance?

Tags: c++, com, interface

Is the above possible?

Can I do this:

```
IUnknown *punk;

punk->QueryInterface(IID_MyInterface, (void**)&m_pMyInterface);
```

I thought that this would tell me if the MyInterface is supported m_pMyInterface...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really mean what you've written above, then no: because your `punk` is an uninitialized pointer.

Normally you need to call `CoCreateInstance` to create an instance of something; after that you can call `QueryInterface` on that instance, to ask what interface[s] it supports.

Comment: so what if the CoCreateInstance return E_NOINTERFACE, what do I do then?

Comment: @Tony That means that the specified class doesn't support that interface: so if you still want to create an instance, either specify a different class or specify a different interface.

Comment: @Tony: Ask CoCreateInstance to return IID_IUnknown, and then do QueryInterface.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. The proposed snippet would test if the object pointed to by `punk` supports the interface with `IID_MyInterface` and if it does support the interface pointer would be retrieved into `m_pMyInterface` and `AddRef()` would have been called on the pointer retrieved. Since `punk` in uninitialized it doen't point to any valid object so trying to call `QueryInterface()` would result in undefined behavior - your program would likely crash.

In order to test if the object pointed to by `m_pMyInterface` supports the interface with `IID_MyInterface` you would need to do the following:

```
IUnknown* punk;
HRESULT hr = m_pMyInterface->QueryInterface(IID_MyInterface, (void**)&punk);
if( SUCCEEDED( hr ) ) {
   //the interface is supported - don't forget that AddRef() has been called
} else {
   //the interface is not supported
}
```

The latter could only be done if `m_pMyInterface` already pointed to a live COM object.